# How to compare to strings after converting them to a double?

Tags: scala

I'm looking for a idiomatic way of converting 2 strings to a double and then comparing them?

To safely convert to double I have:

```
def toDouble(s: String): Option[Double] = {
  try { s.toDouble } catch { case _ => None }
}
```

So I am doing a for expression in order to compare the 2 doubles:

```
for {
  d1 <- toDouble(s1)
  d2 <- toDouble(s2)
} yield (d1 > d2)
```

Now say I wanted to do `(d1 < d2)`, could I somehow generalize this?

Any improvements to make this cleaner?

Comment: What is the intended outcome when one or both of the doubles are `None`? How can you compare something that doesn't exist?

Comment: @Eric I would just return a None, then the calling code will handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import scala.util.Try

     def f(x: String, 
           y: String, 
           compare: (Double, Double) => Boolean): Option[Boolean] = for {
         a <- Try { x.toDouble }.toOption
         b <- Try { y.toDouble }.toOption
     } yield compare(a, b)

scala> f("42", "66", _ < _)
res0: Option[Boolean] = Some(true)

scala> f("42", "66", _ > _)
res1: Option[Boolean] = Some(false)
```

I'd prefer a better type than `Boolean`, so there's room for improvement on my answer.

Comment: `"As Conor McBride puts it, to make use of a Boolean you have to know its provenance so that you can know what it means."` source - https://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/boolean-blindness/

Comment: Nice dropping FP lyrics on me...you are hard core FP :)

Answer (score 1):

The "toDouble" available from [StringLike](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/99a82be91cbb85239f70508f6695c6b21fd3558c/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/StringLike.scala) that you reference throws a NumberFormatException if you attempt to convert something that cannot be converted to Double. It would be "idiomatic" to just use that, but wrap it in scala.util.Try and return the Try.

Returning Try instead of Option would be more idiomatic (and simply better) because None is not semantically indicative to the caller that a problem happened, whereas the Try result (which would look something like `Failure(java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "hi")` would indicate that.

Finally I would skip the For/Yield on this one as it is simpler to just do the following:

```
import scala.util.Try

Try(s1.toDouble < s2.toDouble)
```

Kevin Meredith's answer shows how you can generalize by creating a higher-order function.